# Qt5.9.6 do not follow RPATH to search openssl

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, rpath

I'm working on Qt based project on Linux based OS. We use Qt5.9.6.
When we launch our application, we've got this log from Qt

```
qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
```

After a few research I found that Qt loads the version 1.1 of openssl whereas Qt5.9.6 needs the 1.0.2k version. So I put the right version of openssl next to our application and I set the RPATH accordingly. But it does not works. I'll try with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and that works.

I used `LD_DEBUG=libs` to see where the program try to load the dynamic library and it appears that for Qt, the RPATH is use partially or not at all.

I've created a docker image named `eaglejoe/qtopenssl-bug` with a minimal example.
To compile the example launch

```
cmake --preset default
cmake --build build
```

and launch the program with `build/testqt`

Does someone kwow why the RPATH is not use completely here ?
(In the example it's the RUNPATH  that is used but I have the same issue with a RPATH)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you considered doing a static linked build of openssl 1.0.2 and letting qt5network link directly with that.

Comment: Also, if I recall, Qt will only load openssl dynamically from a "safe" library path (e.g. system folders and not user or environment supplied paths).  Hence, if you can't get libssl 1.0.2 installed in /usr/lib, static linking might be a better option.

Comment: I've considered the static linked but I prefer to avoid that if possible because we are working on embedded platform and we depend on the SDK brought by the manufacturers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing is, Qt loads the OpenSSL library as a plugin, and the dynamic linker `ld.so` on Linux only takes into account the rpath of the executable and/or shared object that calls `dlopen()`. And because Qt itself doesn't have the rpath for your OpenSSL copy set, it won't load it.

The best way around that is (as long as you don't want to recompile Qt yourself with that rpath) to load OpenSSL manually before invoking any Qt function. So add the following to your code at the beginning of `main()`:

```
void* crypto_handle = dlopen("libcrypto.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (!crypto_handle)
    std::cerr << "error loading libcrypto.so: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
void* ssl_handle = dlopen("libssl.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (!ssl_handle)
    std::cerr << "error loading libssl.so: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
```

Note that you must load `libcrypto.so` before `libssl.so`, otherwise `libssl.so` won't load, because `libssl.so` in your installation doesn't have an rpath set for itself, so it won't find the correct `libcypto.so` unless you load that yourself as well.

Further note: technically you could use the official SONAMEs `libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` (yes, even for 1.0.2 those are the correct SONAMEs), but your Qt version is compiled against a weird version of OpenSSL that thinks its SONAME has `1.0.2k` as the extension, not `1.0.0` as it should be, so it will only find the libraries by their generic names, and you have to load the libraries by their generic names (`libssl.so`, `libcrypto.so`) to make the dynamic linker aware that these are aliases.

If both of these are loaded, Qt will be able to work, because then the dynamic linker will see that the libraries in question have already been loaded into the program, and will hence reuse them, without looking for them in the filesystem.

Running your program will then give the following output:

```
build openssl: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
 load openssl: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

That all said: OpenSSL 1.0.2 has not been supported for 2.5 years. And the version you're using, `1.0.2k` is even older, that's from 5.5 years (!) ago. There are several security issues that have been fixed in OpenSSL since, and it is a **really** bad idea to write new code that relies on such outdated software when it comes to network communication.

Please, please use OpenSSL 1.1, which is still supported until September of next year. Qt has support for that since 5.12. From my experience the upgrade from 5.9 to 5.12 was completely painless. Though ideally I'd suggest that new code should use Qt6.

(Unfortunately not even Qt6 appears to [work with OpenSSL 3.0](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-83733) yet, but hopefully that'll change soon.)

Comment: I have to say.. really Thank you! It works really great and thanks for the explanation ! 

About OpenSSL 1.0.2.. I'd like to not use it but we worked on an embedded system and we have to use the Qt Version provide by the manufacturer which is the 5.9.6  :(

Comment: "the dynamic linker ld.so on Linux only takes into account the rpath of the executable and/or shared object that calls dlopen()" 
I make a little test about that and while with RUNPATH this is true, my little test show me that it is not for RPATH. I just create one executable(`main`) and two lib (`lib1` and `lib2`).
Main load lib1 with no dlopen and `lib1` load `lib2` with dlopen. With `lib1` and `lib2` in different folder and the RPATH of `main` points to the location of both libs. And this works perfectly `lib1` use the RPATH of `main` to find `lib2`. So im' still confuse about Qt.

Comment: Regarding your `lib1` / `lib2` example: did you by chance also set an RPATH on `lib1` (cmake often likes to do so if you build stuff with it in the build tree) and that's why the linker finds `lib2`?

Comment: I checked and there is no RPATH on `lib1` only on `main`

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you see with `lib1` and `lib2` here on my system. I've created a [small bare-bones example](https://gist.github.com/chris-se/e8fe3678dc7bf74f46b9a202e5e4399e) that demonstrates the behavior (both for direct linking as well as dynamic loading via `dlopen()`), and it matches what you see with Qt.

Comment: With your example, I obtain a RUNPATH, if I add `--disable-new-dtags` to the link command to get a proper RPATH, it works without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`